# Hibernate bean for jdbc

Tags: hibernate, jdbc

I'm going to create a webapp, and i want to use Hibernate and simple `JDBC` drivers, can i use the same `POJO` with anotation that I use for Hibernate in `JDBC`, or should I create new `BEAN`? You can see my POJO below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="hibernate_test.learner")
public class Learner implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "learner_name", length = 20)
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable (name = "hibernate_test.teacher_learner", joinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "learner_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "teach_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Teacher> teachers;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Set<Teacher> getTeachers() {
        return teachers;
    }
    public void setTeachers(Set<Teacher> teachers) {
        this.teachers = teachers;
    }
    public Learner() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you can but mixing orm with plain sql will cause low quality code, why would you do that? If you are going to write SQL query you can use HQL, Hibernate query language. However, you should've avoid this approach

Comment: Why do you want to use JDBC when you will  use Hibernate too?????

Comment: @WildDev i think In my project i will represent data in table, and if i right it is not good way, first make object from the table, then make table from object. But i want use Hibernate 
because it is easier then JDBS, and i decided combine.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would use JDBC when you're already using Hibernate: your explanation is not very clear. But anyway, no, I wouldn't return instances of Hibernate entities from JDBC methods. It's not that it won't work. But it's just that, when I see a Learner instace being returned from a method, and I know Learner is an entity, I expect that changes to the entity will automatically be persisted. I expect to be able to navigate through associations. That won't be the case if you use JDBC to get the data.

Comment: @Jungle, Hibernate generates everything for you including tables and SQL queries. Hibernate is ORM framework and it does mean you access your database throught object oriented environment and not relational one. So, by considering to use Hibernate in your project you refuse from plain SQL usage. ORM has performance issues thats why plain queries interaction approach is preffered in highload systems but it doesn't mean you should to mix it with orm one. You have to determine what you're going to use in your project, plain JDBC or Hibernate.